# Instagram API GET /Locations/search not working

Tags: api, instagram

Im developing an app that uses the Instagram's API but having trouble using the LOCATIONS endpoint.

The code bellow works, return a list of tags based on the QRY_STRING value

```
instaUrl += 'tags/search?q=QRY_STRING&callback=?';
$.getJSON(instaUrl, accessParam, onInstaListLoaded);
```

The problem is when I try to search by locations, I can query the MEDIA endpoint by latitude/longitude but not the LOCATIONS.

Bellow an example of querying MEDIA by LAT/LNG that works

```
instaUrl += 'media/search??lat=-22.9732708&lng=-43.1857553&callback=?';
$.getJSON(instaUrl, accessParam, onInstaListLoaded);
```

But if I try to query the locations it do not work. Even in the Instagram API Console I get an Internal Error 500 when try to run the same query above changing the MEDIA to LOCATIONS.

Is there any trick to use locations endpoint that is different of the others?

Answer (score 0):

vmenezes,

If it's a 500 error, it's one of 2 things:

1. The location you have for some reason does not register with their back-end processing.
2. More likely, a 500 error is usually never your fault. Something on their back-end is messing up and not able to finish processing your request. I would recommend you [file a ticket](http://instagram.com/developer/support/) under the "Bug Tool".

Please let me know if you have any question!